# how to do `absolute` locating for an element along with `justifyContent`

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to locate my inner div on the right side of its parent with 20px distance from the right and also in the middle vertically. I use the CSS below so it gets to the right side of the parent with 20 px from right but it's not in the middle yet.

```
<div styles={{ position: "relative", display: "flex"}} >
   <div styles={{  position: "absolute", right: 20, justifyContent: "center", }} >
       hello
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of justifyContent: "center", use alignSelf: 'center' in the child div may help you. And to be more accurate output that you like to desire you can add width: 100% and height to some pixels say 40px to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
     return (
        <div className='flex'>
          <div className='box'>Hello</div> 
        </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script><div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use absolute positioning along with a minor transform achieve the expected look.

- `right: 20px` will take the container to the right
- To center align vertically, move 50% from the top and add a -50% transform in the `Y` direction to adjust for the height of the `inner-div`.

```css
.container-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid green;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    HELLO
  </div>
</div>
```